# Consul docker - advertise flag ignored

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul, service-discovery

Hi i have configured a cluster with two nodes (two vm into virtualbox), cluster start correctly but advertise flag seems to be ignored by consul

- vm1 (app) ip 192.168.20.10
- vm2 (web) ip 192.168.20.11

docker-compose vm1 (app)

```
version: '2'
services:
    appconsul:
        build: consul/
        ports:
            - 192.168.20.10:8300:8300
            - 192.168.20.10:8301:8301
            - 192.168.20.10:8301:8301/udp
            - 192.168.20.10:8302:8302
            - 192.168.20.10:8302:8302/udp
            - 192.168.20.10:8400:8400
            - 192.168.20.10:8500:8500
            - 172.32.0.1:53:53/udp
        hostname: node_1
        command: -server -advertise 192.168.20.10 -bootstrap-expect 2 -ui-dir /ui
        networks:
            net-app:

    appregistrator:
        build: registrator/
        hostname: app
        command: consul://192.168.20.10:8500
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
        depends_on:
            - appconsul
        networks:
            net-app:
networks:
    net-app:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.32.0.0/24
```

docker-compose vm2 (web)

```
version: '2'
services:
    webconsul:
        build: consul/
        ports:
            - 192.168.20.11:8300:8300
            - 192.168.20.11:8301:8301
            - 192.168.20.11:8301:8301/udp
            - 192.168.20.11:8302:8302
            - 192.168.20.11:8302:8302/udp
            - 192.168.20.11:8400:8400
            - 192.168.20.11:8500:8500
            - 172.33.0.1:53:53/udp
        hostname: node_2
        command: -server -advertise 192.168.20.11 -join 192.168.20.10
        networks:
            net-web:

    webregistrator:
        build: registrator/
        hostname: web
        command: consul://192.168.20.11:8500
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
        depends_on:
            - webconsul
        networks:
            net-web:
networks:
    net-web:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.33.0.0/24
```

After start i not have error about advertise flag but the services has registered with private ip of internal network instead with IP declared in advertise (192.168.20.10 and 192.168.20.11), any idea?

Attach log of node_1, but they are the same as node_2

```
appconsul_1       | ==> WARNING: Expect Mode enabled, expecting 2 servers
appconsul_1       | ==> WARNING: It is highly recommended to set GOMAXPROCS higher than 1
appconsul_1       | ==> Starting raft data migration...
appconsul_1       | ==> Starting Consul agent...
appconsul_1       | ==> Starting Consul agent RPC...
appconsul_1       | ==> Consul agent running!
appconsul_1       |          Node name: 'node_1'
appconsul_1       |         Datacenter: 'dc1'
appconsul_1       |             Server: true (bootstrap: false)
appconsul_1       |        Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 53, RPC: 8400)
appconsul_1       |       Cluster Addr: 192.168.20.10 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
appconsul_1       |     Gossip encrypt: false, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
appconsul_1       |              Atlas: <disabled>
appconsul_1       | 
appconsul_1       | ==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
appconsul_1       | 
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:24 [INFO] raft: Node at 192.168.20.10:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:24 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node_1 192.168.20.10
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:24 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node_1.dc1 192.168.20.10
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:24 [INFO] consul: adding server node_1 (Addr: 192.168.20.10:8300) (DC: dc1)
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:24 [INFO] consul: adding server node_1.dc1 (Addr: 192.168.20.10:8300) (DC: dc1)
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:25 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:25 [ERR] agent: failed to sync changes: No cluster leader
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:26 [WARN] raft: EnableSingleNode disabled, and no known peers. Aborting election.
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:57:48 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:13 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:22 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node_2 192.168.20.11
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:22 [INFO] consul: adding server node_2 (Addr: 192.168.20.11:8300) (DC: dc1)
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:22 [INFO] consul: Attempting bootstrap with nodes: [192.168.20.10:8300 192.168.20.11:8300]
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout reached, starting election
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] raft: Node at 192.168.20.10:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [WARN] raft: Remote peer 192.168.20.11:8300 does not have local node 192.168.20.10:8300 as a peer
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 2
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] raft: Node at 192.168.20.10:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: node_1
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] raft: pipelining replication to peer 192.168.20.11:8300
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] consul: member 'node_1' joined, marking health alive
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:23 [INFO] consul: member 'node_2' joined, marking health alive
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_solr_1:8983'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8302'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8302:udp'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8301'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8500'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8300'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_mysql_1:3306'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8400'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:53:udp'
appconsul_1       |     2017/06/13 14:58:26 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'app:dockerdata_appconsul_1:8301:udp'
```

Thanks for any reply

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to remove `networks` section from compose file but have same problem, i resolved using compose v1, this configuration works:

compose vm1 (app)

```
appconsul:
    build: consul/
    ports:
        - 192.168.20.10:8300:8300
        - 192.168.20.10:8301:8301
        - 192.168.20.10:8301:8301/udp
        - 192.168.20.10:8302:8302
        - 192.168.20.10:8302:8302/udp
        - 192.168.20.10:8400:8400
        - 192.168.20.10:8500:8500
        - 172.32.0.1:53:53/udp
    hostname: node_1
    command: -server -advertise 192.168.20.10 -bootstrap-expect 2 -ui-dir /ui

appregistrator:
    build: registrator/
    hostname: app
    command: consul://192.168.20.10:8500
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    links:
        - appconsul
```

compose vm2 (web)

```
webconsul:
    build: consul/
    ports:
        - 192.168.20.11:8300:8300
        - 192.168.20.11:8301:8301
        - 192.168.20.11:8301:8301/udp
        - 192.168.20.11:8302:8302
        - 192.168.20.11:8302:8302/udp
        - 192.168.20.11:8400:8400
        - 192.168.20.11:8500:8500
        - 172.33.0.1:53:53/udp
    hostname: node_2
    command: -server -advertise 192.168.20.11 -join 192.168.20.10

webregistrator:
    build: registrator/
    hostname: web
    command: consul://192.168.20.11:8500
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    links:
        - webconsul
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is version of compose file, v2 and v3 have same problem, work only with compose file v1

Comment: What specific part of the compose file v2/3 is the problem? Can you include a working compose file?